# How to create a fixed-length type in flow

Tags: flowtype

I want to create a type that represents 2-character ISO country codes. Is there a simple way to create a type definition for these (or any other fixed-length item)?

Of course one approach would be an enum with the list of all the possible ones

```
type CountryCode = "AX" | "AL" | "DZ" | ...
```

But I'd love something simpler that just enforces 2-character strings.

Do I need to use [dynamic type tests](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#_)?

Comment: no, it's not possible

Answer (score 4):

No, Flow does not have such a feature. It doesn't really have any dependent types features other perhaps types consisting individual values.

You could use tests like `if (countryCode.length === 2) { ... }` like you would normally do in JS, but Flow will not refine the type of `countryCode` inside the `if` block, because there is no Flow type to represent strings of two characters.

In contrast, with actual dynamic *type* tests like `if (countryCode !== null)` Flow will know that `countryCode` is not null inside the if block and can use that knowledge for type checking.

Note that technically you could generate a type that contains 26*26=676 strings of uppercase characters from A to Z: "AA", "AB", ..., "ZY", "ZZ", but that's not an improvement over your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Tuples](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/tuples/) are fixed length, so you could instead represent country codes as a tuple of two numbers (one for each character).

```
type CC = [number, number];

function fromString(str: string): CC {
  if (str.length !== 2) {
    throw new Error("not a cc: " + str);
  }
  return [
    str.charCodeAt(0),
    str.charCodeAt(1),
  ];
}

function toString(cc: CC): string {
  return String.fromCharCode(cc[0]) + String.fromCharCode(cc[1]);
}
```